# Linux - copying only new files from one server to another

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron, scp

I have a server where files are transferred thru FTP to a location. All files are there since transfer beginning (January 2015).
I want to make a new server and transfer the files from first server's location.
Basically, I need a cron job to run scp and transfer only new files since last run.

Connection between servers with ssh is working and I can transfer files without restiction between servers.
How can I achieve this in Ubuntu?

The possible duplicate with the other question doesn't stand because, on my destination server I will have just one file where I should keep the date of last cron run and the files which will be copied from first server will be parsed and deleted afterwards.

rsync will simply make sure that all files exists in both servers, correct?

Comment: Use [`rsync`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync).

Comment: @fedorqui: added supplementary explanation why I don't need the servers to be synced. Thank you!

Comment: OK! [Reopened the post](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33894426/revisions)

Comment: `rsync -azHvu --remove-source-files source destination` should suffice. `-u` will only copy files that are newer or inexistent in destination. `--remove-source-files` will delete the files already synced from source.

Comment: @alvits: I need to use the files copied from source and then delete. Ideal, the destination folder will be empty or there will be only files not processed by a php script yet.

Comment: Are you deleting the destination not the source?

Comment: @alvits: just destination will be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I manage to set-up the cron job on remote computer using the following:

I created first a timestamp file which will keep the last timestamp when cron job run:

```
touch timestamp
```

Then I copy all files with ssh and scp commands:

```
ssh username@remote find <files_path> -type f -newer timestamp | xargs -i scp -i username@remote:'{}' <local_path>
```

Then I touch timestamp file with new modified time:

```
touch -m timestamp
```

The only problem with this script is that, if a file is copied to remote host during ssh run before touching timestamp second time, this file is ignored on later runs.

Later edit:
To be sure that there is no gap between timestamp file and actual run because of ssh command duration, the script was changed to:

```
touch timestamp_new
ssh username@remote find <files_path> -type f -newer timestamp | xargs -i scp -i username@remote:'{}' <local_path>
rm -rf timestamp
mv timestamp_new timestamp
```

Comment: I have a suggestion. How about creating a timestamp using the last file's timestamp as reference? Let's say the last file's timestamp is 1:00pm then timestamp will be 1pm even though your cron took more than 10 minutes to copy all the files and ended up having more files added past 1:00pm. Try `touch -r **lastfile as reference**`

Comment: @alvits: thank you! This is what I did, I was about to post it, but in a slightly different manner. Before ssh i create a new file touch timestamp_new. At end of ssh I remove timstamp and change time of timestamp_new to timestamp.

Comment: Using the latest file as reference will be more accurate won't it? In your method, you could potentially copy files that were already copied if the timestamp file is older than the latest file copied.